# Ubuntu 20 wifi adapter not found wifi not working

Tags: wireless, broadcom, iwlwifi, ubuntu-drivers

On my Ubuntu 20, everything was working fine when suddenly my wifi stopped and all configs were disappeared. At software center it was showing broadcom & legacy driver then I messed it up using lot of commands but nothing worked somehow and that was also removed. I don't know what to do next. I Googled lot but I found nothing related. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the result from terminal for `uname -r`

Comment: 5.8.0-40-generic